# Storybook / Nuxt 3 with script setup component - computed is not defined

Tags: nuxt.js, storybook, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to add storybook to a Nuxt 3 app for some components written with `script setup` mode. But Storybook doesn't recognize the Nuxt *implicit imports* (e.g.: `computed`), and throws: `ReferenceError: computed is not defined`.
How to properly configure Storybook to resolve this?

Component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ greet }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const $props = defineProps<{
  name: string
}>()

const greet = computed(() => `Hello ${$props.name}`)
</script>
```

Story:

```js
import Greet from "./Greet.vue"

export default {
  title: "Greet",
  component: Greet,
  argTypes: {}
}

const Template = (args) => ({
  components: { Greet },
  setup() {
    return { args }
  },
  template: '<Greet v-bind="args" />'
})

export const Default = Template.bind({})
Default.args = {
  name: "John Doe"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This repo shows how you can solve this: https://github.com/lautr/initium-nuxt

It uses `unplugin-auto-import` and `unplugin-vue-components`.

I have shown an example below for if you are using `vite`. This is a `vite.config.ts` file inside of your `storybook/` directory:

```
// vite.config.ts
import { URL, fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    AutoImport({
      imports: ['vue', 'vue-router'],
      dirs: ['./composables'], // Point to your composables directory that is auto-imported
      vueTemplate: true
    }),
    Components({
      dirs: ['./components/'], // Point to your components directory that is auto-imported
      dts: true,
      directoryAsNamespace: true
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': fileURLToPath(new URL('../hex-blog-src/', import.meta.url))
      // Add any other aliases you use in your code base
      // https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config/#alias
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **component**, you need to **import the Vue dependencies**:

```
import { computed } from 'vue';
```

Probably, you are using `unplugin-auto-import` and `unplugin-vue-components`. They work well for the build of Vue/Nuxt itself, but are not taken up by the storybook webpack build, therefore there is the need to import Vue dependencies manually.

Comment: I'm not using any of those plugins, it's Nuxt (3.0.0) that auto imports stuff. The idea is to do it without touching the components.